# What model do you get from PA without addition and multiplication?

Tags: natural-numbers, peano-axioms, first-order-logic

I have the feeling that this question is trivial, but I cannot figure the answer by myself nor from the stuff I have read. So the question is if addition (and multiplication) can be shown as a theorem of PA (without the arithmetical axioms but with successor and induction). If not they are independent and  first order PA+¬A has a model (A=addition + multiplication axioms). What does a model of such system looks like?

Comment: Interpret the function symbol for addition and the function symbol for multiplication in a way that makes the addition axioms and multiplication axioms false. Almost anything will work, like the ordinary natural numbers $0,1,2,\dots$, usual successor, and addition $x+y$ interpreted as $x+y^2$, and multiplication interpreted in the same way. Almost anything will work.

Comment: But the model that you obtain by negating the axioms must be essentially different than the naturals (which is a model when the axioms are true). Am I wrong?

Comment: The structure under the successor function can be the usual one. Or else we could use a non-standard model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean a standard first-order PA setup.

So we have a language  $L$ with constant symbol $0$, unary function symbol $S$, and binary function symbols $f$ and $g$ (their common names, when they are written in the middle, are $+$ and $\times$).

Make an $L$-structure by using the non-negative integers as the underlying set, and interpreting $0$ and $S$ in the usual way. We want to interpret $f$ and $g$ so that the usual axioms about addition and multiplication are false. It is awfully easy to make things false. For example, interpret $f(x,y)$ as $x^2+2y^2$, and $g(x,y)$ as $2x^2+y^2$. Almost anything will work.

Comment: I kind of understand your answer, but not fully, because I don't understand how your answer is compatible with the fact that two first order theories in which independent axioms have different truth values have essentially different models. In some way you did not define not(+), but a different binary relation that can also be defined within PA+A, but different than + and $\times$.  You just used the same names

Comment: The fact that these binary functions can be defined in standard PA is not relevant. My example could instead have used any two functions from $\mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}$ that are *not* definable, but there is nothing wrong with definable functions, as long as the axioms involving addition and multiplication fail. In fact, they don't all have to fail, the failure of one is enough.

Comment: thanks for your response, but what about the fact that "two first order theories in which independent axioms have different truth values have essentially different models"? Is this statement wrong (because you affirm that both PA+A and PA+¬A can have the same model (that is, $\mathbb{N}$)?

Comment: They can have a model with the same *underlying set.* But the *interpretations* of $f$ and $g$ are different from the usual ones, so the models are not isomorphic.

Comment: Actually, I don't think the naturals satisfy that $a+S(b)=S(a+b)$ if + means $x^2+2y^2$ or any other example within $\mathbb{N}$ that you could find.

Comment: They certainly do not, and deliberately so. You wanted to falsify these axioms. The sentence formula $\forall x\forall y(x+Sy=S(x+y))$ is one of these axioms.

Comment: Please give me another day to think about this!

Comment: You are obviously right! Thanks.

Comment: @julianfernandez: You are welcome. Perhaps another question can be asked, that will be capture more of what you are after.